# How to check certain conditions for custom parameters for devise models during sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have created a user model using devise. I added a custom parameter username which is a string. I want to check that the username must begin with a block letter and raise an alert if it doesn't. What should I add in the users_controller.rb ?

Answer (score 0):

**Nothing.**

If you have setup the param sanitation then you do not need to alter the controller further.

You would add validations to the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  # customize this to your requirements.
  validates :username, presence: true, 
                       length: 2, 
                       uniqueness: true
  validate :username_starts_with_uppercase

  private 

    def username_starts_with_uppercase
      unless username[0] == username[0].capitalize
        errors.add(:username, 'must begin with an uppercase letter.')
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: This will apply when editing the record as well. If you for some reason don't want that you can use `validate :username_starts_with_uppercase, if: :new_record?`

Comment: thanks, it worked :) will the generated error show up as a foundation alert?

Comment: It will be displayed as any other validation error. How that is done depends completely on your app. Devise by default shows the errors at the top of the form.